# Correct way to define an array of one or more strings using the OpenAPI v3 Specification

Tags: arrays, swagger, openapi

I wish to POST an array containing a variable number of strings, such as

> ["string1", "string2", ... "stringN"]

My present OpenAPI document defines it this way:

```
schema:
  type: array
    items:
      description: networkIds
      type: string
```

Is this the correct way to code to the OpenAPi v3 spec, or is there a more precise way to indicate one or more strings within the array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The indentation is wrong – `type` and `items` must be on the same level.

If the array cannot be empty and always has at least 1 item, you can add `minItems: 1` as an additional constraint. If all items must be unique, add `uniqueItems: true`.

```yaml
schema:
  type: array
  items:
    description: networkIds
    type: string
  minItems: 1
```

Comment: Thank you, Helen.  That answers my question.  And, yes, I should have caught the indentation problem before submitting the question.

Comment: This is also a blog I referred to: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-body-array-of-strings